A conjecture about the convexity of matrix functions
$f: S_{++}^n \to \mathbf{R}$ is given, where $S_{++}^n$ denotes the set of all $n$-dimensional positive definite matrices.
Suppose that  $f$ is convex when $n=1$.
The conjecture is whether $f$ is convex when $n>1$.
If we consider $f$ as an elementary function, such as $f(A)=\operatorname{tr}(A), \operatorname{tr}(A^{-1}), x^TAx, -\log(\det(A))$, the proposition holds.
Therefore, when we need to verify the convexity of a matrix function, can we directly consider the case where the positive definite matrix degenerates into a scalar to make the judgment?
Edit(Another version of the problem description)
For $n \times n$ matrices, we write $A \geq 0$ if $A$ is positive semidefinite, and $A \geq  B$ if $A - B \geq  0$. We say a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is matrix convex if, for all integers $n$, it holds that
$$f(tA + (1 - t)B) \leq t f(A) + (1 - t) f(B)$$
for all $n \times n$ hermitian matrices $A, B$ and all $t \in (0, 1)$, where the inequality is with respect to the ordering of positive semidefinite matrices.
Then,my question is the equivalence between matrix convex and convex?

I see what you mean, although you or someone else would have to give a more rigorous definition of "$f$" to have a more formal setting. $f$ here is not one function but a sequence $(f_n)_n$ in which each term is related to the others in some sense (otherwise they wouldn't share the same name), but they're still not acting on the same domain so you have to be careful about how properties transfer from one $f_n$ to the others.

I agree with you.Actually, i think my problem is the equivalence between matrix convex and convex

As for the rigorous definition of matrix convex, here are some reference:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2197309/convexity-of-matrix-trace-functions-a-mapsto-operatornametr-bfa
you can find it in some papers:
https://repub.eur.nl/pub/7025/ei2005-38.pdf

A note on definition of matrix convex functions
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379506000073
